# What is causing CLS on this Site?

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, cumulative-layout-shift

I have a CLS shift on [this site](https://rentalinnovationz.com/), and I can't figure out what is causing it?

Typically Cumulative Layout Shifts are caused by not assigning width/height to images or lazyloading them but that is not the case for this site. Also, all of my important CSS is inlined so we don't have an issue with render blocking. I'm really at a loss. Performance insights and Lighthouse are not giving me any clues.

I've tried to take 101vh off of the body/html, and I've tried to take 80/90vh off of the hero image wrapper (the image is absolute so that is not an issue).

Does anyone have any clues for me?

Comment: You have to explain a little more about what is happening and what you want to avoid. As PageSpeed Insights give you a good score, it is not clear what you mean. When you look at the Insights for desktop, you see that 3 header elements have an (small) CLS impact

Comment: I'd like to figure out why the CLS is happening, what is causing the shift? I've never had CLS that I could not fix in the past. -Thanks!

Comment: What Layout shift are your experiencing? I saw a little change in the header height. That one is mentioned in the pagespeed insights report. So look at these elements and see why they are changing. If you are experience something else, try to describe whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below Chrome extensions to find CLS issues.

1. [Web Vitals](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-vitals/ahfhijdlegdabablpippeagghigmibma) Enable console logging for this and in the Chrome dev console, check the entries[n].LayoutShift.sources[n].LayoutShiftAttribution properties
2. [Core Web Vitals Annotations](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/core-web-vitals-annotatio/gjegofcnbogmeijackegenkifhkgkigi)